# How to make ts-jest work with import/export syntax of the js files that are being imported in my imports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

`jest` fails to import the import of my import which is causing `npm run test` command to fail with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` at first line of my `bar.ts` file. For this example `foo.js` is a local file, not  a node module. I can change `foo.js` to `foo.ts` and change the import in `bar.ts` but that is not the solution.

Files in my **src** folder:

- `foo.js`:

```js
export const magicNumber = 42;
```

- `bar.ts`:

```js
import { magicNumber } from './foo.js';

export const secondMagicNumber = magicNumber / 2;
```

- `bar.test.ts`:

```js
import { secondMagicNumber } from './bar';
import assert from 'assert';

it('should work', function() {
    assert.strictEqual(secondMagicNumber, 21);
});
```

Files in the **root** folder:

- `jest.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

- `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "testing-with-jest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.2",
    "typescript": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

- `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",                         
    "module": "ESNext",                    
    "outDir": "./dist",                                       
    "strict": true,                          
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So the problem is that both `ts-jest` and `jest` are tricky to set up for the ES6 import/export syntax. I did exactly that by:

1. Installing both `jest` and `ts-jest` >= 27.0.0 versions.
2. Using this minimal config:

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {                    
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "allowJs": true                
  }
}
```

`jest.config.ts`:

```js
export default {
    globals: {
        extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts', '.js'],
        'ts-jest': {
            useESM: true
        }
    },

    preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts-esm',

    // from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57916712/15076557
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        'node_modules/(?!(module-that-needs-to-be-transformed)/)' 
    ]
}
```